# Google search Console with lack of data

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, data

I am not very good with Google Search Console, but I noticed that on one of the websites of the company I work for, the data just dropped to 0 on the 13 Jan and there is no data until 19 of March.
What could have happened?
On Google Analytics side that did not happen.
Thank you

Comment: The analytics data that you have connected to Google Search Console dropped, or some other data?

Comment: Hello, the data that is collected by search console it self